# Scrolling through a page like Slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came across apples new pages for iPhone5C, iPhone5S, Mac Pro and noticed a nice effect that they seem to be doing for their product pages. I stead of just having the user scroll freely throughout the page, they set up slides (for lack of better term) that when the user scrolls, no matter the amount, they only are able to go through the slides one at a time.
[Iphone5C](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/)
[Iphone5S](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/)
[Mac Pro](http://www.apple.com/mac-pro/)
This is a really nice effect and I wasn't sure if anyone had a method or idea on how to recreate this. Someone posted a script that he wrote to mimic this effect but wasn't sure if there any plugins that were built already. Any ideas or help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this effect is being done via CSS, like this:

```
element.style {
    opacity: 0.9999999999999956;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
}
```

For a further explanation of this technique read [Apple Mac Pro page deconstructed](http://ihatetomatoes.net/apple-mac-pro-page-deconstructed/).

Comment: While this is true, it seems that there is some JS involved to do this, or at least detect the mouse scroll and add/remove the active classes. Thats the part I'm trying to figure out. The animations can come later but its the navigation I'm trying to pull off

Comment: I found a good solution of using reveal.js and mixing it in with a bootstrap to get the look and feel I wanted. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2055617 - great, glad you found what you wanted. Feel free to up-vote the answer. :-)

Comment: [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) is a plugin which do exactly this.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a bit late to answer but yeah, there's a plugin to do this.

It is called [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

- [Living demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
- [Web page](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)
- [Github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

It works with old browsers too, such as IE 8 and has many options such as callbacks, loops...

Check it out :)

Comment: This is actually perfect! The one downside to the solution I ended up using was there was no side navigation/progress like in yours. Good work man!